# Finding installed Java versions actually being used on Linux servers?

Tags: java, linux

Our Linux servers (1500 of them) has multiple Java versions installed (from Java 1.5 to Java 17) and we are in process of cleaning it up. is there a way to find out which installed versions are actually being used?

we can take a snapshot of a process running at any point but this will miss the process which comes for a second and goes down.

Anyway to automate capturing this data, we have options to run ansible playbooks etc.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For java version:
java -version
For java primary compiler:
javac -version

you can run:
whereis java
So you find the java path / or you can: sudo update-alternatives --config java so it list all the java installations and you can select the default

Comment: what mechanisms on your server are in place to start a java process that "comes for a second"? usually Java is used for things like long running servers like tomcat, that sit there and maybe launch another process, but all with the same Java version.

Do you really have cron jobs or something like that, which are executed directly with Java?

Answer (score 0):

The brute force solution (will include downtime and a lot of work):

1. Prepare a documentation of all installed services, either create it or get it at hand
2. Remove or disable all versions of Java
3. Start one service after another
4. Record all errors happening
5. Fill in the necessary Java version for each service in the documentation (probably you can find out by the logs which Java version is necessary for what service)
6. Reinstall or enable one version of Java at a time - probably best the one for the service you just were trying to bring up again

Repeat for all services / java versions.

And for the future: keep records of the services that are running on your server and which dependencies they have.

Comment: we have 1500 servers. so need something which is more automated, updated the post to indicate the same.

Comment: So do the 1500 server all run different stuff with different versions of Java? Or are they just part of a cluster with all similar machines, just multiplied to get more computing power?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script that might work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    ps -aux | grep java | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} lsof -p {} | grep ' txt ' | awk '{print $9}' >> log
    sort -u log > sorter
    cat sorter > log
    sleep .2
done
```

Every 200 milliseconds, it feeds the process id of every currently running process with "java" in it as the argument to the list-open-files utility, filters that list to include only executable files ( "txt" ), and appends that to a file called log. Then it writes the unique strings from that file to a file called sorter and then writes that back to the log file.

I executed a simple java Console app a few times with two different jvms while the script ran, and here's the contents of the log file:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer has two parts.

1. See answer from @pete_bc for his script.
2. Take the output of that script then do a for loop that does something like:

for javaFullpath in "${yourSortedListOfJavaPaths}"; do
listOfJavaVersions+=( $("$javaFullpath" -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}') )
done

So, to put it all together, this requires bash 4.4 or later because use of mapfile:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMETOCAPTURE=86400 #seconds in 1 day
SECONDS=0

#determine the executable paths of the javas that are being used
while [[ $SECONDS -lt $TIMETOCAPTURE ]]; do
    ps -aux | grep java | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} lsof -p {} | grep ' txt ' | awk '{print $9}' >> log
    sort -u log > sorter
    cat sorter > log
    sleep .2
done

#determine their versions
mapfile -t sortedListOfJavaFullpaths < log 
for javaFullpath in "${sortedListOfJavaFullpaths }"; do
    listOfJavaVersions+=( $("$javaFullpath" -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}') )
done
```

Answer (score -2):

Running a ansible playbook and capturing the output to a excel sheet would be a good starting point.